Denen in middle of a sentence

Die Grippe, auch Influenza genannt, ist eine hochansteckende Krankheit, die weltweit verbreitet ist und in Deutschland vor allem in den Wintermonaten auftritt. Auch wenn die Symptome denen einer Erkältung ähneln,...

I know that denen is a Relativpronomen in the plural dative case, however how is it used in the above? very clearly, it is not a Relativsatz that the word comes in...

No, denen is not a relative pronoun here.

Basically the same question: Understanding usage of denen That question has a relative clause, but denen has the same role in both sentences, and it's not a relative pronoun.

"Denen" is not a Relativpronomen but a Demonstrativpronomen. Here it is used to avoid repeating "Symptom", to which it relates to - or, in other words, for which it stands in for. The sentence could be rewritten as:

Auch wenn die Symptome den Symptomen einer Grippe ähneln, ...

It would be considered ugly, though, because repeating words (without some exculpating justification) is to be avoided. This is why "denen" is used instead. In English this is done too, one might say:

Even though the symptoms are similar to those of an influenza ...


So when we have a backward reference through an article, that is also conjugated as a relative pronoun

@Babu: the difference between articles and pronouns is blurred in German, (the often look and a inflected the same), but basically: yes.

In the sentence above, denen is not a relative pronoun. It is a demonstrative pronoun.

@RHa: you are right: 5 edits and you arrive at the opposite of what you intend to say. Thanks.
